# Change CSS on HTML button click?

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to modify the CSS of a page (hide elements of a certain class, "class") when a user clicks a button. I can't seem to find the correct JavaScript for getting this button to trigger the style change. I would prefer to avoid jQuery in my solution.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>hide "class"</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="hide_class()">hide class</button>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function hide_class() {

    document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function (event) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName(".class")) {
            var x = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: Here is my *manifest.json* and *background.js*

Manifest.json (does not reference content.js):

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "my extension",
"description": "it doesnt work",
"version": "0.1",
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": false
 },

"permissions": [
"declarativeContent"
 ],

"page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },  

 "icons" : { "16": "16.png",
          "48": "48.png",
          "128": "128.png" },

  }
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
  {
    conditions: [
      new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: { urlContains: 'g' }, //url contains g
      })
    ],
    actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
  }
 ]);
 });
 });
```

Comment: do you want to add listener or change style?

Comment: I want to change the style when the button is clicked, but I believe I need to implement the listener to change the style, unless someone has a better idea on how to accomplish this.

Comment: listener listens to changes, it does not initiates changes

Comment: Your "wondering" regarding your Chrome extension can not be addressed without more code (i.e. a complete [mcve] that includes your *manifest.json* and any background script). However, your content script does have to get injected into the page somehow. There are two ways to do so, either a `content_script` entry in *manifest.json* or using  `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` in your background script/popup.

Comment: I was not sure if more code was necessary but I've updated it for the sake of clarity

Answer (score 2):

You could add an event listener to the element.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="hide_me">
  I will hide if you click me
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('hide_me').addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y1gc01zj/1

**EDIT**
you could also add a css class:

**CSS**

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('hide_me').addEventListener('click', function () {
    //  this.style.display = 'none';
  this.classList.add('hide')
});
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm trying to implement but how would you recommend triggering this script (content.js) on button click (popup.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for this:

```js
function sw(cl, v) {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
  for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) a[i].style.visibility = v;
}
```

```html
<p class="c1">c1</p>
<p class="c2">c2</p>
<p class="c1">c1</p>

<button onclick="sw('c1', '');">show c1</button>
<button onclick="sw('c1', 'hidden');">hide c1</button>

<button onclick="sw('c2', '');">show c2</button>
<button onclick="sw('c2', 'hidden');">hide c2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this typo:

in `function hide_class() {`

`if(document.getElementsByClassName(".class")) {`

should be

`if(document.getElementsByClassName("class")) {`